# Proposing the Addition of Introductions/Description area within a Topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

I'd like to propose the addition of a topic introduction or topic description area above the Examples in a topic and below the Topic title. When a user is creating a new topic they will not only title the topic but also provide an intro/description which can also be edited (like the topic title can be, from the same panel).

I've provided a mock-up of what the topic page would look like with the addition of an introduction/description section below the topic title but before the examples. See below:
[image: what the topic page would look like with the addition of an introduction/description section]

When one thinks of documentation it is usually expected to be able to go to a topic and find a description or introduction to the specific topic and then more details/examples.

Currently in Documentation here on the SO beta, many topics dive right into examples with little to no introduction unless the author of the topic example decides to provide the information within their example. This distracts from the examples and makes the introduction/description seem out of place. I believe this is because there is no designated place or request for a topic introduction/description leaving authors no choice but to leave one out or add it into their example which may lead to multiple repeated descriptions of a topic.

Since most of us authoring these examples are already familiar with the topics we may overlook adding an intro or description within our example. For some of us that may be okay, but for users who will come to Documentation looking for a better understanding of a topic, or need a refresher on the topic before diving into examples, it may be confusing and inconvenient.

I believe that with this simple addition we can provide more information and context for the user regardless of their knowledge level on the topic when they are coming into the Documentation to look at examples.

**edit:** I'd like to add that I am aware of the `Remarks` section within Documentation. Since there are users creating examples and using them to put an introduction for a topic rather than using the `Remarks` area I believe this shows that it is rather unintuitive. On top of this, the `Remarks` are all the way at the bottom of the topic page, which is out of the way. I also feel that the word Remark is probably not the best word to use if the intention is to "help readers better understand the examples for this topic." Perhaps another way to work this suggestion would be to rename `Remarks` and move it higher on the page.

Comment: Have you forgotten the `Remarks` section?

Comment: The remarks section is at the bottom of the page, which in my opinion is out of the way and not where one would expect to find information about the topic at hand. I think it is more intuitive to expect the topic description to be before examples are shown. I think if anything perhaps I could suggest `Remarks` should be moved to the top or maybe be changed from being named Remarks to something else? 

When I see `Remarks` I think something that is just mentioned briefly rather than something I would go to to find detailed information. Might just be me though. :)

Comment: I see a lot of "examples" that are introductions listed in the examples section. It'd probably be easier and more productive to provide a special section for them rather than fighting it.

Comment: I've interest in writing short overview articles. I know that the new Documentation feature is all about examples, but I'm just surprised there's no provision for any kind of "article" or "article-like" information. Examples on CodeProject often start with an introduction. Is that something different than what Documentation is trying to achieve?

Comment: When writing the intro, try to answer things like: "What is it" "When to use it" "Why this instead of something else"

Comment: And what about "related topics".  The PHP manual is very good at that (at least in the Functions docs).

Comment: I think this is a good idea because it would give the section some focus. Right now some sections are more like a random collection of loosely related things but a description explaining more precisely what the topic is about may help people to keep the contributions more relevant.